# Is (int)0 the same as null pointer by '=='?

Tags: c, pointers, null-pointer

I was confused if I can use `if(ptr == 0)` for `if(ptr == NULL)`. I found there are many questions and answers to this. They said 1. All null pointers compare same. 2. A null pointer is not guaranteed to have all bits set to zero. But I doubt that can be an answer to the question because...
According to 6.3.2.3 p3 and p4 in C99,

> 3. An integer constant expression with the value 0, or such an expression cast to type
>    void *, is called a *null pointer constant*. 55) If a null pointer constant is converted to a
>    pointer type, the resulting pointer, called a *null pointer*, is guaranteed to compare unequal
>    to a pointer to any object or function.

> 4. Conversion of a null pointer to another pointer type yields a null pointer of that type. Any two null pointers compare equal.

`0` is a null pointer constant, and `NULL` in 'stddef.h' is a null pointer constant(`0` or `(void *)0`). The comparison between `0` and `(void *)0` or a null pointer is not defined(the standard just says any two null pointers compare equal).

Then is it really safe to use `if(ptr == 0)` instead of `if(ptr == NULL)` when checking a validity of a pointer? (finally I want to use `if(!ptr)` and I know the original form is good for readability.)

Comment: 6.5.9,5 describes comparison of a pointer and a null pointer constant. Through that rule, both `ptr == 0` and `(void*)0 == 0` are defined (with the obvious meanings).

Comment: Just to be clear, you can use 0 or NULL, and they compare equal to each other, and comparing either to a pointer tells you if the pointer is a null pointer or not. I think the part you were missing was 6.5.9.5 which describes how == works when one of the operands is a pointer and the other a null pointer constant (converting the null pointer constant into the type of the pointer before comparison occurs).

Comment: @Paul Hankin Thanks a lot! The 6.5.9.5 exactly says 0 is the same as NULL when using '==' with a null pointer. I saw that but couldn't catch the point. Now I can be sure. Anyway I don't think my question is duplicated by above link.

Comment: I think there's enough overlap between your question and the linked question and top answer that it's ok for it to be a dupe. Perhaps if this question were cut down to the a specific (and technical) point about the application of the standard to `ptr == 0` then it would be different, but to be honest I don't think it's worth anyone's time, and you got your answer.